# Will iPhone app be rejected for not supporting iPhone 5 screen size?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

Will Apple reject a newly submitted iPhone app that does not support the iPhone 5's screen dimensions, ie runs in compatibility mode and is built to the iPhone 4's screen dimensions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>No, its not necessary. You will notice during submission to [`http://itunesconnect.apple.com/`](http://itunesconnect.apple.com/) Screen shots of iPhone 5 (4 inch retina ) are optional.</strike>

**UPDATE:**

Now 4 inch retina screenshots are necessary to submit iPhone application on Apple AppStore.
Means now you have to support iPhone 5 in every new app you submit to apple store, event when you submit a new version to existing application.

Answer (score 2):

No, It won't get rejected. It will be acceptable by the App Store. Don't worry.

Comment: Are you sure @Rajan Balana...

Comment: @Vishal Yes I am 100% sure.

Comment: I am sure that it won't get rejected. Published another app on app store approx. 10 days ago, no problem. Don't worry...

Answer (score 1):

It won't be rejected for this reason.
B'coz, it works well on iPhone 5 also except black patches at top and bottom.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary that, all the apps are bound to be compatible for iPhone5. Some of them might be only meant for iPhone 4 or 4s. Then also It will work on iPhone5 with black patches at both top and bottom for the remaining screen.

So your app will definitely be accepted by Apple!